# Step in the proof of martingale condition

Tags: martingales, stopping-times

Let X a $L^2$ martingale. We want to prove that $E[(X_t-X_{t\land \tau})^2-\langle X\rangle_t +\langle X\rangle_{t\land\tau}|\mathcal F_s]=(X_s-X_{s\land \tau})^2-\langle X\rangle_s +\langle X\rangle_{s\land\tau}$.

In more than one proof I see the following approach for proving the martingale condition: $
E[(X_t-X_{t\land \tau})^2-\langle X\rangle_t +\langle X\rangle_{t\land\tau}(\mathbb1_{\tau\le s}+\mathbb1_{s<\tau<t}+\mathbb1_{\tau\ge t})|\mathcal F_s]$

we can see after some steps that:

$E[\big((X_t-X_{t\land \tau})^2-\langle X\rangle_t +\langle X\rangle_{t\land\tau}\big)\mathbb1_{s<\tau<t}|\mathcal F_s]=0$

SHOW:
$$E\bigg[E\big[\big((X_t-X_{t\land \tau})^2-\langle X\rangle_t +\langle X\rangle_{t\land\tau}\big)| \mathcal F_{s\lor\tau} \big ]\mathbb1_{s<\tau<t}|\mathcal F_s\bigg]=E\bigg[E\big[\big((X_t-X_{s\lor \tau})^2-\langle X\rangle_t +\langle X\rangle_{s\lor\tau}\big)| \mathcal F_{s\lor\tau} \big ]\mathbb1_{s<\tau<t}|\mathcal F_s\bigg]=E[0\mathbb1_{s<\tau<t}|\mathcal F_s]=0$$

$E[\big((X_t-X_{t\land \tau})^2-\langle X\rangle_t +\langle X\rangle_{t\land\tau}\big)\mathbb1_{\tau\ge t}|\mathcal F_s]=0$

therefore we obtain: $$E[\big((X_t-X_{t\land \tau})^2-\langle X\rangle_t +\langle X\rangle_{t\land\tau}\big)(\mathbb1_{\tau<s}+\mathbb1_{s<\tau<t}+\mathbb1_{\tau>t})|\mathcal F_s]=\big((X_s-X_{s\land \tau})^2-\langle X\rangle_s +\langle X\rangle_{s\land\tau}\big)\mathbb1_{s<\tau}$$ and we have proved that:

$$E[(X_t-X_{t\land \tau})^2-\langle X\rangle_t +\langle X\rangle_{t\land\tau}|\mathcal F_s]=(X_s-X_{s\land \tau})^2-\langle X\rangle_s +\langle X\rangle_{s\land\tau}$$

What I don't understand is why can I remove the indicator function on the last step and conclude that it hold on the general case??

Comment: It's wrong. In fact $X_{s\wedge t} 1_{s < \tau} = X_{s} 1_{s < \tau}$

Comment: @user159517, so it is not possible to conclude that $E[X_{t\land \tau}|\mathcal F_s]=X_{s\land \tau}$?

Comment: Can you post a link to one of the proofs you are reading, to make sure there isn't something being lost in your retelling?

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm sorry but is an approach that has been used during a class for solving two exercise, I don't have a direct link.

Comment: Hm.  It seems to me that there are other problems with the argument.  For instance, the event $\{\tau = s\}$ seems to not have been considered.  Also, I do not believe that $E[X_{t \wedge \tau} 1_{\tau > t} \mid \mathcal{F}_s]=0$ is true in general - I can think of counterexamples.  So I suspect either the approach is wrong, or there are assumptions you have left out, or you have misunderstood or miscopied it.

Comment: @NateEldredge No of course is not true in general, I'm referring to a specific case. Okey, now I will write it in a more accurate way for contextualize it.

Comment: @NateEldredge please give a look, I modified it principally for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are some typos.  Your equation following "therefore we obtain" should read

$$E[\big((X_t-X_{t\land \tau})^2-\langle X\rangle_t +\langle X\rangle_{t\land\tau}\big)(\mathbb1_{\tau \le s}+\mathbb1_{s<\tau<t}+\mathbb1_{\tau \ge t})|\mathcal F_s]=\big((X_s-X_{s\land \tau})^2-\langle X\rangle_s +\langle X\rangle_{s\land\tau}\big)\mathbb1_{\tau \le s}$$
since the term that has not been shown to vanish has $\mathbb{1}_{\tau \le s}$, not $\mathbb{1}_{s < \tau}$.

Now notice that when $\tau > s$ we have $s \wedge \tau = s$ and therefore
$$\big((X_s-X_{s\land \tau})^2-\langle X\rangle_s +\langle X\rangle_{s\land\tau}\big)\mathbb1_{\tau > s} = \big((X_s-X_{s})^2-\langle X\rangle_s +\langle X\rangle_{s}\big)\mathbb1_{\tau > s} = 0.$$

Thus, we do in fact have
$$\begin{align*}\big((X_s-X_{s\land \tau})^2-\langle X\rangle_s +\langle X\rangle_{s\land\tau}\big)\mathbb1_{\tau \le s} &= \big((X_s-X_{s\land \tau})^2-\langle X\rangle_s +\langle X\rangle_{s\land\tau}\big)(\mathbb1_{\tau \le s} + \mathbb{1}_{\tau > s}) \\&= (X_s-X_{s\land \tau})^2-\langle X\rangle_s +\langle X\rangle_{s\land\tau}\end{align*}$$