# indicator function, stopping time and measurability

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, martingales, stopping-times

Let $s < t$. Let $\tau$ be a stopping time. Let M, N square integrable martingale.

In a proof that i'm following i read that: 
$$E\big[E[N_{\tau}(M_{\tau} - M_t)\mathbb1_{\tau\le t}|\mathcal F_{s\lor\tau}]|\mathcal F_s\big]=      E[N_{\tau}(M_{\tau} - M_{\tau\lor s})\mathbb1_{\tau\le t}|\mathcal F_s]$$

what i don't understand is why $\mathbb1_{\tau\le t}$ can go outside the expectation without have any change, it seems that the explanation is that it is $F_{s\lor\tau}$ measurable, but instead i think that it is $F_{t}$ measurable and that $ F_{s\lor\tau} \subset F_{t}$. Any help?

Comment: Isn't this just a consequence of the tower property of conditional expectation, because $\mathcal F_s\subset\mathcal F_{s\vee\tau}$?

Comment: ah you mean bringing outside $N(M_t-M_\tau$ modifying the time according to the conditional expectation and then bring it inside again for expoiting the tower property?

Comment: I simply mean that for any integrable $Z$, $E\left[ E[Z\mid\mathcal F_{s\vee \tau}]\mid \mathcal F_s\right] = E\left[ Z\mid \mathcal F_s\right] $.

Comment: yes, of course, but did you notice that there was a change on the equality? from $M_t$ to $M_{t \lor s}$. What it mean is that it has not being simply applied the tower property

Comment: I missed that.  And now the indicator $\Bbb 1_{\tau\le t}$ bothers me, because it isn't measurable with respect to $\mathcal F_{s\vee\tau}$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins so the proof of NCh is it wrong? is it measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal F_t$?

Comment: @JohnDawkins https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3490881/step-in-the-proof-of-martingale-condition if you look at this my previous question I added specifically the steps of the proof where the same problem present here happen. (are the two line after SHOW )

Comment: @JohnDawkins What step of proof seems wrong to you? It is just the definition.

Comment: @Buddy_ It is true that $\{\tau\leq t\} \in \mathcal F_t$, by definition. And this fact is useless for the equality since it cannote help bring indicator outside the  inner expectation. And it is wrong that $\mathcal F_{s\lor\tau} \subset \mathcal F_{t}$ for $s<t$. Take $A=\{\tau=t+1\}\in \mathcal F_{s\lor\tau}$, and this event dos not belong in general to $\mathcal F_{t}$.

Comment: @NCh thank you for this last comment, it was really helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, $\{\tau\leq t\}\in F_{s\lor\tau}$. 
By definition, $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F_\tau$ is
$$
\mathcal F_\tau:=\left\{A\in\mathcal F:A\cap\left\{\tau\le u\right\}\in\mathcal F_u\;\text{for all }u\right\}
$$
Then 
$$
F_{s\lor\tau} = \{A\in\mathcal F: A\cap \{\max(s,\tau) \leq u\} \in \mathcal F_u \text{ for all } u\} = \{A\in\mathcal F: A\cap \{s\leq u\}\cap \{\tau \leq u\} \in \mathcal F_u \text{ for all } u\} 
$$
Look at $A=\{\tau\leq t\}$ and check whether it belongs to $F_{s\lor\tau}$.
$$
\{\tau\leq t\}\cap\{s\leq u\}\cap \{\tau \leq u\} = \{\tau\leq t\land u\}\cap\{s\leq u\} \in \mathcal F_u.
$$
So, $\{\tau\leq t\}\in F_{s\lor\tau}$.