# Measurability of a stopped local martingale

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

Let $X_t$ be a local martingale.
Let $\tau_n$ be a localizing sequence.

We then know that $$E[X_{t\land \tau_n}|\mathcal F_s]=X_{s\land\tau_n}$$
$1)$ But $X_{s\land\tau_n}$ is measurable w.r.t wich sigma algebra? is it $\mathcal F_s$ measurable?

$2)$ Moreover, if i have $E[e^{X_{t\land \tau_n} + t\land \tau_n}|\mathcal F_s]=1$ can I bring on the other side $t\land \tau_n$ obtaining: $E[e^{X_{t\land \tau_n}}|\mathcal F_s]=e^{- t\land \tau_n}$? I think that it is not possible because $\tau_n$ is not $\mathcal F_s$ measurable, but then is measurable w.r.t. to what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is measurable w.r.t $\mathcal F_{s \wedge \tau_n}$ and $F_{s \wedge \tau_n} \subset \mathcal F_s$.

$e^{t\wedge \tau_n}$ is measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal F_t$. So it is legitimate to bring it to RHS only when you know that $t \leq s$.

Comment: Okey, thank you, i added a second part of the question, if you wish to give a look

Comment: @Buddy_ I have edited my answer.

Comment: could you provide a proof of $e^{t\land \tau_n}$ being $\mathcal F_t$ measurable?

Comment: @Buddy_ For any stopping time $\tau$ we know that $t \wedge \tau$ is measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal F_t$. This implies that $g(t \wedge \tau)$ is measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal F_t$ for any  measurable function $g$.

Comment: $\mathbb 1_{s \le \tau \le t}$ is it $\mathcal F_t$ or $\mathcal F_\tau$ measurable?

Comment: Because i'm still trying to understand this step (but I think that there is a mistake on the solution) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3497615/indicator-function-stopping-time-and-measurability

Comment: @Buddy_ $1_{s \leq \tau \leq t}$ is measurable w.r.t. both $\mathcal F_{\tau}$ and  $\mathcal F_{t}$.